# Is is possible for protocols to introduce new state into existing classes?

Tags: clojure

I understand how protocols can be used to introduce new behaviour to existing classes, but is it possible for them (or any other Clojure mechanism) to introduce state to existing classes? More specifically, I would like to be able to associate a map with instances of a class that comes from a 3rd-party library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Protocols are conceptually similar in Java Interfaces in that they don't concern themselves with state or representation at all, so I'm pretty sure you can't do it that way unless you store the state outside the object itself. You can however use the various other ways of extending (subclassing) classes in Clojure to do this, e.g. using a `proxy` or with `gen-class`. (see 
http://clojure.org/java_interop#Java%20Interop-Implementing%20Interfaces%20and%20Extending%20Classes)

Comment: It looks like I'll have to use a combination of `gen-class` and `gen-interface`. The interface will define the functions to get the state. I was hoping to do this in a more dynamic way in order to introduce state to a relatively large number of existing classes, but `reify` doesn't work for concrete classes. Maybe using `gen-interface` and then generating proxies on demand would do it?

Comment: You could add the state with gen-class and handle the rest with protocols. Not sure if this will make things simpler, but I think the optimal solution will depend heavily on the specifics of your situation.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a protocol with `set-state` and `get-state` functions. Then extend them to the classes you want, with an implementation built around a hashmap of some kind. You can't store the state in the foreign objects, but you can have your functions share a ref of a hashtable keyed by object. I think this solution may have a number of problems, like how do you detect when an object will be GCed and its state needs to be cleared as well? You can use a WeakReference or something, but it isn't trivial.

Comment: It's possible to do this, but I wouldn't recommend it. as you note, it's a lot of hassle, and proxy or reify already allow you to capture state using closures, which should make the GC issues go away (and generally work more like you'd expect a lisp to work)

Comment: I agree that this isn't a great solution, but it could be necessary if  the class in question is marked as `final`, in which case `proxy` won't help (and I don't think `gen-class` can overcome that description).

Answer (score 2):

First off, protocols are interface definitions, and generally, you don't want to specify state in an interface. You generally want to put state in an *implementation* of an interface, see below.

For most of the clojure constructs that allow you to implement interfaces or extend classes the sanest way - especially if you don't own the class - is to use closures to capture state. You can capture mutable types to implement mutable state (though that's *probably* something you want to avoid if you can).

An immutable example from http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/reify

```
 (str (let [f "foo"] 
      (reify Object 
        (toString [this] f))))
```

Note that f here could be a ref or a var or an atom instead of a string if you want mutable state.

EDIT: as noticed in the comments, I might not have made this completely clear: you can use defprotocol to define a function-based interface, and then use reify to create instances of that protocol to capture state.

EDIT 2: Sorry for making this confusing. This code won't actually work for existing classes, because reify does't support it. Proxy probably works as an alternative, though the documentation doesn't flat-out states that function names in a protocol map 1-1 to interface methods.

Comment: The example only instantiates a single object; there aren't any other object instances. reify is not a class definition (at least not conceptually). The OP can bundle it up in a function to bind f at the time of the call to reify to whatever is needed.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I just realised that (only saw your comment after deleting) - still won't help the OP as you can't reify on a class, only interfaces or protocols.

Comment: But defprotocol just defines an interface. I will make that more clear in my post.

Comment: The question states "... is it possible for them (or any other Clojure mechanism) to introduce state to existing *classes*"

Comment: and you can, using reify and protocols. The docs for protocols even have an explicit example of using reify with protocols.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get it. Let's take some existing Java class, say `java.lang.Exception`. We want to add `set-foo` and `get-foo` to it, which we'll define in a protocol, and which should set/get an instance variable. How does reify help here?

Comment: Ah, right. That's my mistake. I was assuming you could use reify to extend classes, but you can only extend the class Object or interfaces/protocols.

Comment: Thanks, but as you said it won't work. I'll give it a try with `gen-interface` and `proxy`.

Answer (score 0):

You can store state. You just need to use an atom or a ref and reference and dereference that atom or ref in your get and set methods

Comment: That will be *global* state, though, not per-instance state.